# React custom hook for fetching data: how to solve the state inconsistency between loading and error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im' writing a custom hook to fetch some data. I'd like to use in in two different scenarios, based on the `manual` argument:

**Scenario 1**: automatic data fetch on component mount (`manual` is `false`):

```ts
const MyComponent = () => {
  // Automatic mode: data fetching on mount
  const { loading, data, error } = useOrders(false);

  return (<></>);
};
```

This works without issues: as `manual` is `false`, `loading` is `true` as soon as component renders.

**Scenario 2**: in `useEffect` based on some conditions (`manual` is `true`):

```ts
const Modal = () => {
  // Manual mode: fetch every time modal is shown
  const { fetch, loading, data, error } = useOrders(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    isOpen && fetch();
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (<></>);
};
```

This scenario is problematic because `loading` starts as `false`, then it become `true` as soon as `useEffect` is executed. There is a little time window where:

- `loading` is `false`
- `error` is `null`

Show/hide child components based on these two states is problematic. For example:

```
{loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
{!loading && !error && <p>Hello world!</p>}
```

... will show these components for a brief time period between the rendering and the `useEffect` execution.

The actual hook implementation is:

```ts
const useOrders = (manual: boolean) => {
  const [{ loading, error, data }, setState] = useState<{
    loading: boolean,
    error: null | unknown,
    data: Order[]
  }>({ loading: !manual, error: null, data: [] });

  const fetch = useCallback(async () => {
    setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: true, error: null }));

    return axios.get<Order[]>('/api/orders')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: false, data }));

        return data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, loading: false, error }));

        throw error;
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    !manual && fetch();
  }, [manual]);

  return { fetch, loading, error, data };
}
```

Comment: What is isOpen? And when it is changing?

Comment: Add another state entry called `settled`, default it to false and set it to true when the request is done - [`useFetch`](https://use-http.com/) exposes `response` for instance.

Comment: use a very short setTimeout in the useEffect (perhaps even 5 milliseconds), and set another state to true after this time has passed (loading will be false by then)

Answer (score 0):

The initial state of loading should be be true, instead of `!manual`

```js
  const [{ loading, error, data }, setState] = useState<{
    loading: boolean,
    error: null | unknown,
    data: Order[]
  }>({ loading: true, error: null, data: [] });
```